# Variables en Scopes Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Me gustaría saber si conocen una forma de pasar una variable hacia un slot, ésta sea reactiva.

Componente `ViewHeader.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot name="izquierda"></slot>
        <slot name="centro"></slot>
        <slot name="derecha"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Componente Padre `Dashboard.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <view-header>
            <template v-slot:derecha>
                <button v-if="esCreacion">Crear</button>
                <button v-else>Editar</button>
            </template>
        </view-header>
    </div>
</template>
```

Por lo tanto, mi intención es que si en el padre cambia la variable `esCreacion`, el botón cambie de texto de **Crear** a **Editar**.

El tema es que al montar el componente toma la variable en su estado inicial (`true`), pero cuando cambia a `false`, el botón no cambia de texto.

¿Saben cómo hacer que la variable ingresada al slot sea reactiva?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tus templates tu no estás pasando una variable como tal a ningún slot del componente hijo al que te refieres, solamente estás pasando contenido de slot de acuerdo a una variable del componente padre, entonces funcionaría así:

```js
Vue.component('view-header', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <slot name="izquierda"></slot>
      <slot name="centro"></slot>
      <slot name="derecha"></slot>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    esCreacion: true
  },
  methods: {
    toggleButton() {
      this.esCreacion = !this.esCreacion
    }
  },
  computed: {
    buttonName() {
      return this.esCreacion ? 'Crear' : 'Editar'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <view-header>
    <template v-slot:derecha>
      <button @click="toggleButton">{{ buttonName }}</button>
    </template>    
  </view-header>
</div>
```